# QR decomposition with lower triangular matrix using Householder reflection

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

### Problem

> Find householder matrices $H_1,H_2,\cdots,H_n$ such that
>
> $$
> H_n\cdots H_1 A = L
> $$

where $A$ : $n \times n$ matrix and $L$ : $n \times n$ **lower triangular matrix**.

---

### Try

By defining $v_k:= [\cdots, sgn(x_k) |x_k|, \cdots]$ and $H_k := I - 2v_kv_k^T/v_k^Tv_k$, we can make

$$
H_n\cdots H_1 A = U
$$

where $U$ : $n \times n$ **upper triangular matrix**

But I'm currently stuck at how to define $v_k$ to make RHS lower triangular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start from the last column, you are then in almost the same setting as for the $QR$ with upper $R$: you start with the column that will be transformed to a column with only zeros except for one coefficient (but it will be $\lambda e_n$ instead of $\lambda e_1$), and continue as usual.

Alternately, you can do that with the same algorithm as usual ($QR$ with upper $R$), by first reversing the order of the columns and rows of $A$, and doing the same afterwards on $Q$ and $R$. You can apply this to all Householder reflections, and you can check that a "reversed" reflection $H_k$ is still a Householder reflection with reversed $v_k$.

Note that if $f$ is the function that reverses the order of rows and columns, then $f(AB)=f(A)f(B)$. I don't know if it has a specific notation.

Comment: Reverting the rows of A is a particular permutation , which is made by left multiplying A with the [exchange Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix), (J) which is in fact a permutation matrix. If you multiply on the right you revert the columns.  Then JJ=I and f(AB) = JABJ= JAJJBJ = (JAJ)(JBJ)

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut, I think the method is not correct. When you apply the QR decomposition, we need to sub the new Householder matrix in a block, and the overall matrix is not a householder matrix. I don't think it could be carried on.

Comment: @JamesChiu It doesn't matter. As above call $f$ the function that reverses the order of rows and columns, then write the QR decomposition of $f(A)$: $f(A)=QR$, then apply $f$ to the result: $A=f(Q)f(R)$, and $f(R)$ is lower triangular. And of course $f(Q)$ is still orthogonal. As to the "sub" Householder reflections $H_k$, they are equivalent to $n\times n$ block matrix, with a Householder reflection as one block, and the identity matric as the other. The blocks get exchanged, and while the reflection is modified, the identity remains the identity.

Comment: But after you put it into a block. Is that still a Householder matrix? As the question is asking for finding a sequence of Householder matrix.

Comment: @JamesChiu Yes. I understand that I didn't address completely your previous comment. They are Householder matrices of decreasing dimension, completed by the identity - but they are *also* "true" Householder matrices: consider the matrix $I-2vv^T/||v||^2$. If $v$ is too short, complete $v$ with zeros and you still get a Householder matrix. See? It's also a block matrix with the identity and a smaller Householder matrix (I am more used to write it this way, but it's immaterial).

Comment: I see thank you very much