# Notation for reversed rows and/or columns of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, notation

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3232638/43608) I am using a transformation of matrices, and I would like to know if there is a notation for this.

Given a matrix $A$, let $B$ be the same as $A$ with rows in reverse order, $C$ with the columns in reverse order, and $D$ with both rows and columns in reverse order. Is there a usual notation for any of $B,C$ or $D$ ?

The $D$ case has a nice property: if it's called $f$, then for any matrices $A,B$, $f(AB)=f(A)f(B)$.

I know one can write for instance $B=A[n:1,:]$ and it's not uncommon to see such MATLAB-like formulas in numerical analysis articles, but I wonder if there is a shorthand for this, or a usual name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of anything like that in standard mathematical usage, but the APL programming language has operators $C = ⌽A$ and $B = \ominus A$.

Then your theorem is that $$⌽\ominus(XY) = (⌽\ominus X)(⌽\ominus Y)$$ or more briefly that $⌽\ominus$ is a homomorphism.  (Clearly, $⌽\ominus = \ominus⌽$.)

Probably nobody would complain much if you used something like that.

Comment: I didn't think of APL. Interesting notation. Following your suggestion, I found a list of APL symbols [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_syntax_and_symbols#Monadic_functions).

Answer (score 2):

The $n\times n$ permutation matrix $(J_n)$ with ones along counter-diagonal (often called the [exchange matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix)) can perform the indicated transformations.
Given $A \in {\mathbb C}^{n\times m}\;$
the transformations are
$$\eqalign{
J_nA &= A\big[n:1,\,:\big] \\
AJ_m &= A\big[:\,,\,m:1\big] \\
J_nAJ_m &= A\big[n:1,\,m:1\big] \\
}$$
And the "nice property" is a consequence of the
involutory nature of the exchange matrix.
$$\eqalign{
f(AB) &= J_n(AB)J_k \\
 &= J_nA(J_mJ_m)BJ_k &\qquad \{J_m^2=I\} \\
 &= (J_nAJ_m)\,(J_mBJ_k) \\
 &= f(A)\,f(B) \\
}$$

Comment: Thanks. That's certainly the most interesting approach for applications, where there are often many matrix products in a row, and hence possible simplifications (such as $JJ=I$ here).